# Can someone help me identify my voice type?

Tags: voice

I am Male/14. My morning voice is C2 and my normal speaking voice is D#2. The highest note I can hit is A2. Is this considered bass or low baritone?

Comment: Identifying vocal range is a lot more complex than that. It requires a session with a professional and doesn't simply boil down to "lowest note" or "currently available range".

Comment: I think your octave notation is probably different to the normal scientific pitch notation.

Comment: Whatever it is now will probably be quite different from what it could be in two or three years time.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to help you out by quoting a very good friend who teaches singing professionally. But, ideally, as I had stated in my comment to your original post, you want a session with a professional to identify your range. It's not as simple as finding out what your lowest note is and what range you can squeeze yourself into.

> Voice types originate from the classical world of opera. They are literally a "type cast" for actors. In a choir context, it is the literal note/pitch range which that voice will sing in, so it has nothing to do with the instrument of the vocalist and everything to do with the written part/sheet music. In opera, the concern is different. Opera is sung without a microphone, and you can't rely on numbers to carry the sound, so operatic singing has to resonate very loudly. It is this resonance that will determine the voice type of the singer. An easy exercise for finding your voice type is to play at 3 standard ranges (e.g. bass, baritone, tenor) without making any changes or adjustment to what you're doing and trying to figure out in which of those three ranges your voice sounds loudest without you trying. This sounds simple, but within the context of singing lessons I often find people really struggle at not making any adjustments whatsoever. So the goal is to find the range at which you resonate loudly with little effort. The idea is to cast voice types in order to ensure longevity of the instrument and increase likelihood that the audience will be able to hear all roles.

Additionally, given you have provided your age and gender:

> For most boys the prime voice change period is 14-15, while for girls it tends to range from 12 to 18 (this also includes massive variability with onset of periods). Most classical teachers will refuse to take on a student, male or female, until they are 16, and the lessons will be cautious until the mid-twenties often...

So please be very careful and, ideally, find a professional to help you out. Especially at such a critical age.